# Angular ignoring CSS transform property

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created an overlay component for showing a loading spinner using Angular Material;

`overlay.component.html`:

```
<div id="overlay">
  <mat-progress-spinner id="spinner" color="accent" mode="indeterminate" diameter="100"></mat-progress-spinner>
</div>
```

`overlay.component.css`:

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: default;
}

#spinner {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The `transform` properties (`transform`, `-o-transform`, `-moz-transform`, `-webkit-transform`) are being ignored but if I use `margin`(s) properties (since the `diameter` of `mat-progress-spinner` is known), the `mat-progress-spinner` would be rendered exactly at the center of the screen:

```
#spinner {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Why Angular is ignoring the transform property?

***Angular ver: 10.0.5***

***Angular Material 10.1.2***

Comment: have you tried adding: transform(-50%, -50%)!important;

Comment: Yes; still the same

Comment: and you could try adding the style in your main styles.scss file, but I assume you have already tried that?

Comment: yes, tried that; no effect.

Comment: can you remove top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

Comment: Obviously that puts the spinner in the top left corner of the screen.